# Optimization of interface extending interface in java

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface A with two methods:

```
public interface A{
    method One();
    method Two();
}
```

And I have two options for `interface B`:

Case 1:

```
public interface B{
    method One();
    method Two();
    method Three();
}
```

Case 2:

```
public interface B extends A{
    method Three();
}
```

Can anyone tell me which of the above two cases is better to implement and why?
Which are the downsides of Case 2?

Edit: In interface B, I need both the methods of interface A. So, I thought extending would be much better.
**There are some classes where I need method One and Two only, there I implement interface A. And where I need method One, Two and Three, I implement interface B.**

Comment: You should do what you believe is clearest and simplest.

Comment: To me, case 2 is more clearer, i was just thinking if there is any downside of using case 2?

Comment: @kaze I agree, the only downside to case 2 is that you can't give the method in `B` different javadoc. See Collection and Set as an example.  If you don't have this requirement I wouldn't try to be DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) instead of WET (Write Everything Twice)

Comment: @kaze Sorry, I mean I try to be DRY rather than WET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on your logic. Consider these two pairs of interfaces:

```
interface House {
    int doorCount();
    int windowCount();
}

interface Automobile {
    int doorCount();
    int windowCount();
    int wheelCount();
}
```

Nobody in his right mind would derive `Automobile` by extending a house, because an automobile is *not* a house with wheels.

On the other hand, in situation like this

```
interface House {
    int doorCount();
    int windowCount();
}

int Mansion extends House {
    int poolCount();
}
```

deriving from `House` makes sense, because `Mansion` is a kind of `House` with "additional features".

Comment: exactly. So, there is no downside in **Mansion extends House**

Comment: @kaze Correct, there's only upside: you can write code that processes `House` in terms of `House`'s interface, without thinking that some houses are mansions.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you need to do. If `method Three()` introduces functionality that from the design point of view should be encapsulated into another unit (such as interface or class) then use 2 if it's similar functionality use 1.

EDIT:
There is also one more option: interfaces don't have extend each other and concrete class may implement them both, but again - depends on what you need

EDIT2:
After your edit it still doesn't make much of a difference. Still class can implement two interfaces or one and still you can use polymorphic assignment on both classes. For example if `class concreteA implements interfaceA` and `clas concreteB implements interfaceB` or `class concreteB implements interfaceA, interfaceB` you can still do `InterfaceA classB = new concreteB();`

Answer (score 1):

If you go with Case 1, and you already have client code written against the type `A`, it will fail to work with instances of classes which implement `B`, and for a purely red-tape reason: `B` is conceptually an extension of `A`, but modeled in the Java type system as a disparate type.

Example:

```
static void existingMethod(A a) {
  ...work with a ...
}

class ImplB implements B { ... }

public static void main(String... args) {
   B b = new B();
   existingMethod(b); // compile error for Case 1; Case 2 compiles fine.
}
```

Therefore it would make much more sense to have your `B` type extend `A`.

Comment: I have checked. What exactly did you want me to notice in the added text?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to look at the type of relationship between `A` and `B`.

If `B` "is a" `A`, then it would make more sense to go with case 2.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you use the interfaces for. If all interfaces that use interface A also use interface B, then you may as well use case 1 and get rid of interface A all together. Otherwise, there is no reason to duplicate code. Duplicating code means that if you change something, you have to change it everywhere, instead of just one place.

Comment: In that case I would use method 2, because it reduces code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

If you have A and want to use it, you can go for B extends A. If you extend B from A only because of reuse method declaration, then your concrete class has to implement all 3 methods and that is drawback (not much use) when you are concentrating only B.